# Вырезать область изображения по координатам полигона?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

У меня есть координаты многоугольника внутри изображения.

Поволяет ли OpenCv вырезать на новый слой изображение по координатам многоугольника?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Пример (c) @KobeJohn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341538/numpy-opencv-2-how-do-i-crop-non-rectangular-region):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# original image
url = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QXbO.jpg'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
ret,image = cap.read()
# mask defaulting to black for 3-channel and transparent for 4-channel
# (of course replace corners with yours)
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
roi_corners = np.array([[(10,10), (300,300), (10,300)]], dtype=np.int32)
# fill the ROI so it doesn't get wiped out when the mask is applied
channel_count = image.shape[2]  # i.e. 3 or 4 depending on your image
ignore_mask_color = (255,)*channel_count
cv2.fillPoly(mask, roi_corners, ignore_mask_color)
# from Masterfool: use cv2.fillConvexPoly if you know it's convex

# apply the mask
masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image, mask)

# save the result
cv2.imwrite('d:/temp/image_masked.png', masked_image)
```

Изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Да, нужно создать восьмибитную матрицу-маску, нарисовать на ней многоугольник с помощью `cv2.fillPoly`, затем использовать эту маску как аргумент [cvCopy](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#copy)

[Первый пример из гугла](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341538/)

Comment: Можете привести пример пожалуйста, сейчас у меня имеются координаты в таком формате: `[(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]`

Comment: Добавил название нужной функции для рисования многоугольника