# Экстраполяция в python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

В общем есть у меня текстовый файл, в нем данные представлены в таком формате:

```
YYYY MM DD HH MM SS   NAL X   NAL Y  NAL Z    LYR X   LYR Y  LYR Z   
2015 01 01 00 00 00   7821.3  1002.6 53990.2  7154.0  781.9  54297.5
```

Сначала дата, потом X, Y, Z по разным обсерваториям, обсерваторий этих много. Так вот, мне нужно по X и Y выстроить координатную сетку и построить изолинии, но данных Z недостаточно и их нужно экстраполировать, собственно вопрос, как реализовать это в python?

Comment: вы можете выложить ваш файл на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: @MaxU
https://yadi.sk/d/AVdDWi6B3Y2tmx

Comment: @MaxU Ну получается эти значения Z будут известны только точках по главной диагонали координатной сетки, разве нет?

Comment: @MaxU, можете объяснить как это сделать?

Comment: Я не знаю элегантного способа... Попробуйте открыть вопрос в англоязычном SO с метками: `pandas`, `matplotlib`, `numpy`, `python` и со ссылкой на файл с данными. Там аудитория на порядки больше - шанс получить толковый ответ, соответственно, тоже

Comment: @MaxU *"шансы получить толковый ответ [на порядок больше]"* -- попробуйте с помощью данных по доле вопросов с одобренным (плюс или принят) ответами подтвердить это утверждение (думаю что это не так). Если вы правы, то легко должно быть разницу на целый порядок продемонстрировать.

Comment: вы хотите контурный график построить? Как contour в matplotlib?

Comment: @jfs, приличная часть ответов здесь скопирована/переведена/сделана по образу уже существующих ответов из англоязычной версии SO. Я думаю число "неотвеченных" ответов здесь было бы гораздо более значительным если бы не существующие похожие ответы на англоязычной версии SO.

Comment: @MaxU: что вы хотите сказать, что "приличной части" ответом не было бы на русском, если бы не было их английских аналогов? Вы это можете как то обосновать? К примеру, я не наблюдаю "приличной части" копирования для своих ответов (могу единицы случаев вспомнить, когда ответ к переводу сводился <1%—можно меня опровергнуть найдя всего 15 моих ответов-переводов, если есть [у меня меньше 1500 ответов на ru.SO]). Если речь  о "приличной части" -- это должно быть не сложно сделать.

Comment: @jfs, вы единственный кто дает ответы на русскоязычном SO? Если хотите поищите сами 15 или больше ответов (не только ваших), использующих ответы с англоязычной версии SO. Кстати, не все кто дает ответы честно указывают на авторство... Я за последние несколько дней использовал ответы с Eng. SO уже несколько раз: [пример1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/843630/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86-%d0%b2-hive/843635?s=1|0.0000#843635), [пример2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/843094/211923).

Comment: @jfs, предлагаю сконцетрироваться на поиске ответа, а не на этом бесполезном споре....

Comment: @MaxU: безграмотность поражает. Если *не только мои* (меньше 1500) ответы рассматривать, то чтобы продемонстрировать, что более 1% ответов-переводов, то естественно что не 15 ответов-переводов нужно найти (к примеру, всего ответов с меткой [python] ~9400 это значит, что уже 95 ответов-переводов нужно найти для метки [python]). Не могу поверить, что приходится объяснять как проценты работают.

Comment: @jfs, что трудный день? понимаю... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Ну наконец-то вы внятно изложили задачу, о чем я вас просил на другом ресурсе.

То, что вы описали - это абсолютно стандартная задача построения изолиний. Непонятно, при чем тут главная диагональ, которую вы во всю "рекламируете". У вас  есть некая матрица. X и Y значения координат. Я надеюсь, эти координаты (обсерваторий) со временем не меняются. Значит упорядочиваем ваши обсерватории сначала по координате Х, потом по координате Y. Получаем вполне нормальную карту точек на плоскости, представленную двумерной матрицей. Это сильноразряженная матрица, но никак не диагональная. Количество отсутствующих данных в этой матрице на много больше, чем значимых.   Значимые данные - только те, которые соответствуют конкретной лаборатории. У такой точки есть значение матрицы и оно равно вашей координате Z. Все, задача сведена к стандартной задаче построения изолиний. Решение легко гуглятся, ну, например:

http://method.meteorf.ru/publ/tr/tr346/k_alf.pdf

http://koi.tspu.ru/koi_books/dolganova/2.3.html

http://www.graphicon.ru/oldgr/grafor/gr_help/chapter_7_2.htm

Все-таки рекомендую начать с того, что-бы немного поднатаскаться в теории. Это поможет вам упорядочить ваши мысли и лучше понимать, что и как надо делать в подобных задачах.  Например -  по книге:

Вестра Э. - Разработка геоприложений на языке Python (2017).

Непонятно другое. Если координаты обсерваторий не меняются во времении, то зачем в каждой строчке данных их повторять снова и снова?  Если использовать более рациональное представление данных, то и объем данных снизится в три раза, и скорость обработки (не надо парсить на каждом шаге). В общем - эффективное представление данных -  половина работы в любом дата-анализе.

Comment: Я файл со всеми данными прикрепил в комментарии, координаты X, Y непостоянны

Comment: Во-первых, непонятно, как может меняться координаты конкретной обсерватории, но допустим. Но вы же изолинию строите по конкретной временной метке (ну, по крайней мере - так следует из вашего описания задачи). Тогда все мои комментарии остаются в силе.  Как минимум до того момента, пока вы не захотите строить временной прогноз изменений изотерм - но об этом тоже не было ни слова в условии задачи. P.S. Файл на обменнике у меня не открывается.

Comment: @НиколайВолков: вы пробовали griddata+ contour?  К примеру: [Matplotlib: gridding irregularly spaced data](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_Gridding_irregularly_spaced_data.html)