# Объединение таблиц в Hive

Tags: sql, hive

В наличии есть две таблицы.

```
tab1: clave, campo, valor, resto
```

и

```
tab2: clave, campo, valor, resto
```

Мне нужно получить итоговую таблицу, в которой идут строки сначала одной таблицы, а потом другой.

Я изначално начал думать в сторону `join`, но те запросы, которые я делал объеденяют таблицы построчно.

Может кто посоветуют в какую сторону направляться?

Версия сервера `HIVE 2.2.0`

Answer (score 2):

[Пример (c) @Lorand Bendig:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14102425/5741205)

```
CREATE TABLE combined AS
SELECT unioned.clave, unioned.campo, unioned.valor, unioned.resto 
FROM (
  SELECT  a.clave, a.campo, a.valor, a.resto 
  FROM tab1 a  
  UNION ALL  
  SELECT b.clave, b.campo, b.valor, b.resto 
  from tab2 b
) unioned;
```